# How do I store several radio buttons at once into MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

this is my PHP script that lists all of my tags (from a MySQL database) with two radio buttons (enable and disable) for each row. how I can save the changes (if I enable or disable something) into the MySQL database? Whether I enable or disable a book it should save the value 1 or 2.

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($row['enabled'] == 1) {
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $row['id'] . '" value="1" checked>Enable' . 
     '<input type="radio" name="' . $row['id'] . '" value="2">Disable ';
} else {
echo '<input type="radio" name="' . $row['id'] . '" value="1">Enable' .  
     '<input type="radio" name="' . $row['id'] . '" value="2" checked>Disable ';
}
echo $row['tagname'] . "<br />";
}
?>
```

Thanks. I hope you understand my question! :-)

Comment: Where is your existing code attempting to insert into the DB?

Comment: Are you looking for UPDATE query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain my code quoted in `/* */` as I go further:

```
<?php

/* ESTABLISH YOUR CONNECTION */

$mysqli=mysqli_connect("Host","Username","Password","Database"); /* JUST REPLACE THE NECESSARY HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD AND DATABASE */

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){

echo "Error".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ /* IF FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED */

/* STORE THE SUBMITTED POST DATA */

$counter=$_POST['hiddencounter'];
$radio=$_POST['radio'];
$id=$_POST['id'];

for($x=0;$x<=$counter;$x++){ /* FOR LOOP BASED ON THE HIDDEN COUNTER */

mysqli_query($mysqli,"UPDATE tags SET enabled='$radio[$x]' WHERE id='$id[$x]'"); /* UPDATE THE enabled COLUMN WITH THE CORRESPONDING SUBMITTED RADION BUTTON */

} /* END OF FOR LOOP */

} /* END OF ISSET */

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM tags ORDER BY id ASC");

echo "<form action='' method='POST'>"; /* SUBMIT ON PAGE ITSELF */

$counter=0; /* WILL SET AS YOUR COUNTER FOR ARRAY PURPOSES */

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

if($row['enabled'] == 1) {
echo "<input type='radio' name='radio[$counter]' value='1' checked> Enable <input type='radio' name='radio[$counter]' value='2'> Disable "; /* STORE THE RADIO BUTTON'S VALUE IN AN ARRAY */
}

else {
echo "<input type='radio' name='radio[$counter]' value='1'> Enable <input type='radio' name='radio[$counter]' value='2' checked> Disable "; /* STORE THE RADIO BUTTON'S VALUE IN AN ARRAY */
}

echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[$counter]' value='$row[id]'>"; /* STORE THE ID IN AN ARRAY */

$counter=$counter+1;
echo $row['tagname'] . "<br />";
} /* END OF WHILE LOOP */

echo "<input type='hidden' name='hiddencounter' value='$counter'>"; /* STORE THE TOTAL COUNT IN THE LOOP */
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Update'>";
echo "</form>";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! Your code did the trick. Have a good weekend to you both of you!

Comment: No problem! Same to you! Happy weekend!

Comment: And lo, the sql injection possibilities,  and subsequent xss attack vulnerabilities,  did abound. Good: using mysqlI Bad: not using prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't save the radiobuttons, but the state. If the state can be enabled or disabled (or: Enabled, yes or no), then you can just store it in a field called `'enabled'`, which is of a boolean type , which is `BOOL` in MySQL.

If you want to leave the possibility open to store other states as well, you might store it in a field called `'state'`, which is of type `INT` or `ENUM`.

BOOL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html (it is an alias for TINYINT(1)

ENUM: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html

Comment: I do actually want to have the possibility to store other states as well. Right now I have the field type as INT, but my main issue is how to save the changes to MySQL. How should I write the code? I mean, if I have 100 tags? Should I use some array stuff?

Comment: I assume every tag is a row in a database? In that case you will probably have a table named `Tags`, which would have two columns `Name` and `State`, where the latter contains the state for that tag. Don't story arrays in a single field.